# how to split one path into two paths in svg

Tags: svg

I'm very new to svg syntax and I want to know how I can split a path into two paths. actually I have something like this:

`M Xm Ym ... C Xc1 Yc1 Xc2 Yc2 Xc3 Yc3 (*) C Xd1 Yd1 Xd2 Yd2 Xd3 Yd3 C ...`

(*) is where I want to split the path

and I want to convert it to two paths like this:

`M Am Bm ... C Ac1 Bc1 Ac2 Bc2 Ac3 Bc3`

and

`M An Bn C Ad1 Bd1 Ad2 Bd2 Ad3 Bd3 ...`

How to calculate A and B numbers by X and Y nums?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can rely on the path commands being absolute (ie capital letters like 'C' rather than 'c'), then it is easy.

```
M Xm Ym ... C Xc1 Yc1 Xc2 Yc2 Xc3 Yc3 (*) C Xd1 Yd1 Xd2 Yd2 Xd3 Yd3 C ...
```

would become

```
M Xm Ym ... C Xc1 Yc1 Xc2 Yc2 Xc3 Yc3
```

and

```
M Xc3 Yc3  C Xd1 Yd1 Xd2 Yd2 Xd3 Yd3 C ...
```

That is, just use the last coordinate pair from the previous path command.

However be aware that, if the path has a fill, splitting it like this may mess up the fill.

If the path has relative path commands (eg. `c`) - particularly the command before the split - then you will need to do a lot more work. You will need to work out what that last coordinate is in absolute terms before you can use them in the inserted `M` command.

**Example:**

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path transform="translate(10,10)"
        d="M -10,0
           C -10,-5.5 -5.5,-10 0,-10
           C 5.5,-10 10,-5.5 10,0"/>
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path transform="translate(10,10)" fill="red"
        d="M -10,0
           C -10,-5.5 -5.5,-10 0,-10"/>
  <path transform="translate(10,10)" fill="green"
        d="M 0,-10
           C 5.5,-10 10,-5.5 10,0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I did this before asking the question but it didn't work.

Comment: Then I think you must have done it wrong.  I've added a demo to demonstrate.