# Error inflating class android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, android-runtime

I am learning Android development I got this error after I change the layout background to a drawable.
I am getting this error

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp, PID: 8595
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp/com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #16 in com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #16 in com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:66)
        at com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:60)
        at com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp:drawable/img7 with resource ID #0x7f0700ee
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/img7.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700ee
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:875)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:669)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1002)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1017)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5579)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:196)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:191)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:66)
        at com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:60)
        at com.hemantmaurya.storemanagementapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: R is not a valid verb. Failure occurred at position 2 of path: STRING_TOO_LARGE
        at android.util.PathParser.nCreatePathDataFromString(Native Method)
        at android.util.PathParser.-$$Nest$smnCreatePathDataFromString(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.util.PathParser$PathData.<init>(PathParser.java:79)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:2043)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1994)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateChildElements(VectorDrawable.java:840)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:738)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:141)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1394)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1355)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:907)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:861)
            ... 37 more
```

Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.
Xml for this

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@drawable/img7">
```

so I created a Image view on that i used that drawable in src attribute but error is same

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/img7"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

after that i used it as background for that imageview but same error

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/img7"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

and i am getting resource not find exception on that same layout file

drawable - img7 and original svg file size is 29.9 Mb

[image]

Comment: Can you show drawable/img7

Comment: you can see now @ShivrajsinhSarvaiya

Comment: androidx.appcompat:appcompat dependency is defined in the gradle file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [long SVG Asset file error : R is not a valid verb. Failure occurred at position 2 of path: STRING\_TOO\_LARGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877282/long-svg-asset-file-error-r-is-not-a-valid-verb-failure-occurred-at-position)

Comment: @SzilárdGerlei Yes there is the dependency added